# Yarn Berry: How to use shared scripts and avoid dependency repetition in child package.json?

Tags: typescript, tsconfig, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I have been trying to follow this [Yarn Berry shared scripts practice](https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/qa#how-to-share-scripts-between-workspaces) , based on @arcanis [comment here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1518#issuecomment-650032877):

My setup is like so:
Yarn: 3.3.1, Zero Installs
Typescript: 4.9.5
Node: 18.13.0

```
├── packages
│   ├── package
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   └── package.json
└── yarn.lock
```

with root package.json:

```
{
  "name": "type-def-repro",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.3.1",
  "volta": {
    "node": "18.13.0",
    "npm": "9.4.0",
    "yarn": "3.3.1"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "packages"
  ]
}
```

worktree `packages` package.json:

```
{
  "name": "@repro/packages",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.3.1",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "package"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "p:tsc": "cd $INIT_CWD && tsc"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.11.18",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  }
}
```

and workspace `package` package.json:

```
{
  "name": "package",
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.3.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "yarn p:tsc"
  }
}
```

and `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDirs": ["./src"],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    ...
    "types": ["node"],
    ...
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

The index.ts file contains simply `console.log("hello")`. 
Upon running script `yarn build` from `packages/package`, I get this error:

```
in package % yarn build                                                                                                             
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
  The file is in the program because:
    Entry point of type library 'node' specified in compilerOptions

  tsconfig.json:28:15
    28     "types": ["node"],
                     ~~~~~~
    File is entry point of type library specified here.


Found 1 error.
```

I was hoping to extract all build tools (tsc, jest, eslint) to a separate (parent) workspace and keep all required dependencies there.
But it looks like I still have to declare in every child workspace dev dependencies `@types/*`.

I have also tried adding this to workspace `package` package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@repro/packages": "*"
  }
```

Removing `types` from `compilerOptions` changes the error to

```
in package % yarn build                                                                                                             
src/index.ts:1:1 - error TS2584: Cannot find name 'console'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to include 'dom'.

1 console.log("hello")
  ~~~~~~~


Found 1 error in src/index.ts:1
```

What am I missing? Do I really have to define dev dependencies `@types/*` in each workspace that want to use that shared script?